# How to use handlebars to handle complex JSON data like this?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nested, handlebars.js

I have read couple posts about handling complex JSON data but haven't found anything similar to the problem I currently have.

Here's how my data is formatted:

```
         var data = {

             "results":{
                 "employees":[
             {"firstName":{"type":"Name", "value":"Doe"}, 
              "lastName":{"type":"Name", "value":"Smith"},
              "birthDay":{"type":"Date", "value":"June"}
             },

             {"firstName":{"type":"Name", "value":"Lucy"}, 
               "lastName":{"type":"Name", "value":"Lee"},
               "birthDay":{"type":"Date", "value":"October"}
             }
             ]
         }}
```

I want to grab all the first names and I have experimented something like this which didn't work:

```
            {{#each results.employees}}
                   {{#each firstName}}
                  Name: {{value}}<br>
                {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
```

The data is parsed through a website and formatted in this way. Preferably I don't want to re-format the JSON file.

Comment: Your keys may need to be `this.employees` (this loop is seeming unnecessary) and `this.firstName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#each` statement is for iterating through an array. The only array in your data is `employees`. The top level element is `results`, then you have the `employees` array as a child, which has a child called `firstName`, which has a child called `value`.

Just follow the same hierarchy:

```
{{#each results.employees}}
   Name: {{firstName.value}}
{{/each}}
```

Points to remember:

1. Only use #each on an array element
2. Work your way down the hierarchy by using the property accessor (dot notation)
3. You must end on a literal value (like a string), or it will print out [object] as you discovered

Comment: I just edited my post and updated a clearer version of the JSON structure. If I am using the method I posted, I will be able to get a bunch of "Name" field but no value (number of Name fields does not correspond to the number of firstName I have either). If I use results.employees.firstName, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match the changes you made to the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that results is not an array so you should not use an each there
instead use something like this

```
{{#each results.employees }}
  Name: {{firstName}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Sorry thought it would work but somehow I was only able to get [object Object]